# Trouble using single BaseAdapter to feed multiple listViews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter, android-adapterview

I had posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985811/use-of-single-baseadapter-for-multiple-listviews) in here yesterday. Since I did not add proper code snippets, I hardly got solution. So here I am, posting it all new. Just to keep active on the questions.

I have three tabs- A, B, C. Each of these tabs is an ActivityGroup class. TabC contains a listView. TabA and TabB has buttons to go to TabC.

XML file of a class in tabC (This is for request coming from Tab **A**)

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ListView
        android:id="@+id/enquiryListViewA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp" >
</LinearLayout>
```

the target class in tabC is

```
public class TestClass extends Activity {
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         if(0 == Constants.requestID) { //requestID is used to identify the tab
             //request from tab A
             setContentView(R.layout.custom_fullpicture_A);
         } else { //request from tab B
             setContentView(R.layout.custom_fullpicture_B);
         }
}
```

And in the Handler class, I am setting adapter. Here also I check the valid listView depending on the tab type

```
 if(0 == Constants.requestID) {
   ListView enquiryView = (ListView) ((Activity) childContext).findViewById(R.id.enquiryListViewA);
   adapterA = new CustomFullPictureAdapter(childContext, msg.obj);
   enquiryView.setAdapter(adapterA);
 } else {
   ListView enquiryView = (ListView) ((Activity) childContext).findViewById(R.id.enquiryListViewB);
   adapterB = new CustomFullPictureAdapter(childContext, msg.obj);
   enquiryView.setAdapter(adapterB);
 }
```

And the getView method of adpater class is

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    System.out.println("Full Picture adapter: CONVERT VIEW : :: " + convertView);
    System.out.println("Data count from DB :: " + getCount());
    int viewType = Constants.requestID;

    View viewAccounts = null;
    View viewCM = null;
    View view = null;
    View masterView = null;

    if(viewType == 0) {
        viewAccounts = convertView;
    } else if(viewType == 1) {
        viewCM = convertView;
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }


    if(viewAccounts == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
         if(!Constants.isLoggedInCustomer) { //logged in as user
             viewAccounts = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fullpicturerow_A, null);

            holder.salesCostAcc = (TextView) viewAccounts.findViewById(R.id.vSalesCostAcc);
            holder.profitAcc = (TextView) viewAccounts.findViewById(R.id.vProfitAcc);
             holder.gpAcc = (TextView) viewAccounts.findViewById(R.id.vGpAcc);
             holder.salesValueAcc = (TextView) viewAccounts.findViewById(R.id.vSalesValueAcc);
             holder.quantityAcc = (TextView) viewAccounts.findViewById(R.id.vQuantityAcc);
             holder.transactionCountAcc = (TextView) viewAccounts.findViewById(R.id.vTransAcc);
             holder.avgPriceAcc = (TextView) viewAccounts.findViewById(R.id.vAvgPriceAcc);
             holder.objectNameAcc = (TextView) viewAccounts.findViewById(R.id.vObjectNameAcc);
             holder.objectCodeAcc = (TextView) viewAccounts.findViewById(R.id.vObjectCodeAcc);

             holder.salesValueAcc.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getSalesValue());
             holder.quantityAcc.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getQuantity());
             holder.transactionCountAcc.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getTransactionCount());
             holder.avgPriceAcc.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getAvgPrice());     
             holder.objectNameAcc.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getObjectName());
             holder.objectCodeAcc.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getObjectCode());

             holder.salesCostAcc.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getSalesCost());
            holder.profitAcc.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getProfit());
             holder.gpAcc.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getProfitMargin());

             masterView = viewAccounts;

             viewAccounts.setTag(holder);
         } else {

         }
    } 



    if(view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
         if(!Constants.isLoggedInCustomer) { //logged in as user
             viewCM = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fullpicturerow_B, null);

            holder.salesCost = (TextView) viewCM.findViewById(R.id.vSalesCost);
            holder.profit = (TextView) viewCM.findViewById(R.id.vProfit);
             holder.gp = (TextView) viewCM.findViewById(R.id.vGp);
             holder.salesValue = (TextView) viewCM.findViewById(R.id.vSalesValue);
             holder.quantity = (TextView) viewCM.findViewById(R.id.vQuantity);
             holder.transactionCount = (TextView) viewCM.findViewById(R.id.vTrans);
             holder.avgPrice = (TextView) viewCM.findViewById(R.id.vAvgPrice);
             holder.objectName = (TextView) viewCM.findViewById(R.id.vObjectName);
             holder.objectCode = (TextView) viewCM.findViewById(R.id.vObjectCode);

             holder.salesValue.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getSalesValue());
             holder.quantity.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getQuantity());
             holder.transactionCount.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getTransactionCount());
             holder.avgPrice.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getAvgPrice());     
             holder.objectName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getObjectName());
             holder.objectCode.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getObjectCode());

             holder.salesCost.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getSalesCost());
            holder.profit.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getProfit());
             holder.gp.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getProfitMargin());

             masterView = viewCM;

             viewCM.setTag(holder);
         } else {

         }
    }

    if(null != masterView)
    holder = (ViewHolder) masterView.getTag();

    if(0 == position % 2)
        masterView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.textColorWhite);
    else
        masterView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.textColorCyan);

    return masterView;
}
```

So here is what happens. User clicks the button from TabA or B to TabC. This will add TestClass to current activity of the tab. Using requestID variable, adapter provides different data to TestClass in TabA and TabB. However, if I switch between tabs, all of them have the same value!

Hope I did not confuse. Please ask in case you have queries. What do you think is blocking?

Comment: So you want different data under different tabs using the same adapter?

Comment: look you can do one thing , use a static variable and on a tab click set the variable to some value and now check that value going to differnt tab once you have this thing done. Then initialize the adapter in the respective classes with different data.

Comment: I am already using that static variable which is Constants.requestID

Comment: what's the issue then? Are you able to initialize adapter with the new data?

Comment: its appears in a tab. but as soon as I switch the tab, the latest data is fed to all listViews! :(

Comment: So you have a single collection or different collection to store the queried data. I am talking about `searchArrayList`

Comment: You're a star! That was indeed the culprit- the list. No need for separate layout XMLs! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you are using a single collection i.e. `searchArrayList` as I can see in your posted code.

You have to **maintain its state properly** to get around with the solution.